# Missing row names in dataframe after using apply on a dataframe with one column selected

Tags: r, apply

So I have made a few functions to provide some descriptive statistics on my data for later usage.

```
#' Gets general summary of features
#'
#' @param data A data.frame with features as columns and samples as rows
#' @return A data.frame with summary information for each feature in data
#'      where each row is a feature and each column is an attribute of the feature
getGeneralSummary = function(data) {
    summaryFunctions = list(
        getClass = function(x) {class(x)},
        countNA = function(x) {sum(is.na(x))},
        hasAllNA = function(x) {sum(is.na(x)) == nrow(data)}
    )
    featureSummary = lapply(data, function(x) {
        lapply(summaryFunctions, function(fun) {
            fun(x)
        })
    })
    featureSummary = do.call(rbind.data.frame, featureSummary)
    colnames(featureSummary) = c('class', 'numNA', 'hasAllNA')
    return(featureSummary)
}

#' Gets descriptive summary of a character class feature
#'
#' @param feature A character vector
#' @return A data.frame that provides descriptive summary of feature
#'      $ category1 : number of occurrence for category1
#'      $ ...
#'      $ categoryN : number of occurence for categoryN
#' @export
getCharSummary = function(feature) {
    dataDesc = cbind(summary(as.factor(feature)))
    colnames(dataDesc) = c("count")
    return(dataDesc)
}
```

which was used to provide a description for all character/factor class columns, using the below code snippet:

```
    dataDesc = list()
    dataDesc$general = getGeneralSummary(data)
    char = dataDesc$general$class == 'factor' | dataDesc$general$class == 'character'
    dataDesc$char = apply(
        data[char],
        MARGIN = 2,
        FUN = function(x) {
            getCharSummary(x)
        }
    )
```

where `dataDesc$general` has a `class` column that describes each feature in the data. I tried this on the iris data set and I got:

```
$char
     Species
[1,]      50
[2,]      50
[3,]      50
```

instead of:

```
$char$Species
             count
sentosa         50
versicolor      50
virginica       50
```

I think the apply messed the intended outcome, but am not sure how to fix it. I know the above code works for when there are more than one column in the data that are factor/character class.

Comment: Could you provide the code for `getGeneralSummary`?

Comment: you could use `lapply(data[char], getCharSummary)` which gives me the expected result instead of `apply`

Comment: specifically you can't use apply because `In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set, so that (for example) factor results will be coerced to a character array.` if you test this with using `print(getCharSummary(x))` instead of just `getCharSummary(x)` in your `apply`, you can see the difference

Comment: just added `getGeneralSummary`